# sum of squares equals the product of their roots

Tags: number-theory

I was doing some math about a three by three magic square of squares, and I managed to prove that there are some numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $$\alpha^2 + \beta^2=\alpha\beta$$  Is this ever possible, and if so, is there some formula to generate such numbers?

Comment: $0\le(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab$ so $a^2+b^2>2ab>ab$ for positive integers $a,b$ (and indeed for positive reals, but I assume you are talking about positive integers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's never possible (except for $a=b=0$).

$$a^2+b^2=ab$$

$$a^2-ab+b^2=0$$

$$a=\frac{b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4b^2}}{2}=\frac{b\pm b\sqrt{-3}}{2}$$
There are no real $b\ne0$ for which $a$ would be real too.

---

Another way of looking at it: the square of the hypothenuse is very evidently always bigger than the rectangle formed by two perpendicular legs of a right triangle (ab=ch where h is the height of the triangle, and that's always smaller than c).

Comment: Great answer! ${}{}{}$